# possible circular referencing?

Tags: c++, vector

Maybe it's because I've been staring at this for 5 hours straight and I'm just reading over the obvious solution, but Xcode states that my vector of objects (that is declared in a header file) is undeclared in one .cpp file; however, my other .cpp file can access the vector, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Maybe my header files are out of place, or I'm unintentionally "circular referencing"?? Suggestions please?

**publications.h**

```
#ifndef PUBLICATIONS_H
#define PUBLICATIONS_H

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Publication {
    private:
        string
            publication_title,
            publication_author,
            publication_year,
            publication_genre,
            publication_media,
            publication_target_age,
            publication_ISBN;

        bool currently_checked_out;

    public:
        Publication(string title, string author, string year, string genre, string media, string target_age, string ISBN, bool checked_out) {
            publication_title = title;
            publication_author = author;
            publication_year = year;
            publication_genre = genre;
            publication_media = media;
            publication_target_age = target_age;
            publication_ISBN = ISBN;
            currently_checked_out = checked_out;
        }

        Publication(){};

};
#endif /* PUBLICATIONS_H */
```

**library.h**

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Publication;

class Library {
    private:
        vector<Publication> lb;

    public:
        Library(){};

        void documentation();
        void list_all_publications();
        void new_publication(string title, string author, string year, string genre, string media, string target_age, string ISBN, bool currently_checked_out);
};
#endif /* LIBRARY_H */
```

**patron.h**

```
#ifndef PATRON_H
#define PATRON_H

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Publication;

class Patron {
    private:
        string
            customer_name,
            customer_telephone;

    public:

        void check_out_publication(string publication_requested);
        void return_publication(string check_in_publication_name);
        void check_out();
        bool is_checked_out();

        Patron(){};


};
#endif /* PATRON_H */
```

library.cpp (works perfectly fine, ***can*** access vector in library.h)

```
#include "library.h"
#include "patron.h"
#include "publications.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

Patron p;

void Library::documentation() {
    cout << "\n-----Create a new publication----\n";
    cout << "You will enter all the necessary info for a new publication (title, author, year, genre, media, target age, and ISBN).\n";

    cout << "\n----List all Publications-----\n";
    cout << "List all publications that have been entered (in this current session).\n";

    cout << "\n---Check out Publication----\n";
    cout << "You will enter your name and telephone number and the publication will be checked out.\n";

    cout << "\n-----Return Publication------\n";
    cout << "A previously checked out publication will be marked as returned.\n";
}

void Library::new_publication(string title, string author, string year, string genre, string media, string target_age, string ISBN, bool checked_out) {

    lb.push_back(Publication(title, author, year, genre, media, target_age, ISBN, checked_out));
}

void Library::list_all_publications() {
    for (int i = 0; i < lb.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Title: " << "\tChecked Out: " << p.is_checked_out() << endl;
    }

}
```

patron.cpp (problematic file, ***cannot*** access vector in library.h)

```
#include "publications.h"
#include "library.h"
#include "patron.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

void Patron::check_out_publication(string publication_requested) {
    // check to make sure publication isn't already checked out.

    for (int i = 0; i < lb.size(); i++) {

        if ((publication_requested == lb[i].publication_title) && lb[i].currently_checked_out) {
            cout << "Sorry, this publication is currently checked out." << endl;

        } else if ((publication_requested == lb[i].publication_title) && !(lb[i].currently_checked_out)) {
            cout << "Enter your name: ";
            getline(cin, customer_name);

            cout << "Enter your telephone number (no dashes/no spaces): ";
            cin >> customer_telephone;
        } else {
            continue;

        }
    }

}

void Patron::return_publication(string check_in) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lb.size(); i++) {
        if ((check_in == lb[i].publication_title) && lb[i].currently_checked_out) {
            // marked as no longer checked out.
            lb[i].currently_checked_out = false;
        }
    }
}

bool Patron::is_checked_out() {
     return currently_checked_out;
}

void Patron::check_out() {
   currently_checked_out = true;
}
```

Error in patron.cpp

```
USE OF UNDECLARED IDENTIFIER "lb"
```

Comment: `library.h` must `#include "publications.h"`. As you have it now, it is undefined behaviour (library declares a vector of incomplete type)

Comment: Your error message is nothing to do with includes; in `Patron::check_out_publication` you write `for (int i = 0; i < lb.size(); i++)`, but there is no variable called `lb` there.  `lb` is a member of `Library`, but this is a function of `Patron`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lb` is a private member of the `Library` class. You can access it in your library.cpp file because you are using it within a `Library` member function. Whereas in the `Patron` class you're directly accessing it. But the compiler sees it as just another variable, which you haven't declared. Likely you need to add an accessor to `Library`.

Comment: would `Library library` work as an accessor? I'm new to C++ so I'm still trying to understand...

Comment: @David No, that just creates a variable of type `Library`. Anything that uses this object does not have direct access to the private members of `library`.  There are several webpages that can help you out. Try searching for "c++ accessor". Since this is likely to bite you, you'll also want to learn the difference between returning copies of data and references since C++ uses copies by default.